# notification near a location

Tags: android, gps

I want to know if there is any way to notify a user when he is near a particular location.
when the the user gets near the location a notification comes to his phone reminding him of his location.

I m trying following code but its not working.

`public class NotifyuserActivity extends Activity {

     LocationManager locMan;

     double lat;

     double lon;

     NotificationManager notMan;`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    locMan=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,10, mylistener);
}
```

LocationListener mylistener= new LocationListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        CharSequence from = "AlarmManager - Time's up!";
        CharSequence message = "This is your alert";        
        Location tasklocation=new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double dis1 = location.distanceTo(tasklocation);
        tasklocation.setLatitude(22.727733);
        tasklocation.setLongitude(75.886079);
        if(dis1 < 200.00)
        {

            notMan = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Click here for details", System.currentTimeMillis());

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotifyuserActivity.this,NotifyuserActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotifyuserActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

         n.setLatestEventInfo(NotifyuserActivity.this, from,message, pendingIntent);
           notMan.notify(10001, n);
           Toast.makeText(NotifyuserActivity.this,"Distance to location is: " + dis1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

`}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with this so much, but you set the requested location (i.e taskLocation.setLat\setLong...) after you measure the distance.
Also, you only said, it's not working. what does it do? what does work?

Comment: actually i want to use this module in my project. ya i have tried writing tasklocation above dis but it is also not working

Answer (score 1):

here Location change code..try this.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("in onlocationchanged");
         String locationString=location.convert(location.getLatitude(),1);
         Toast.makeText(this,"locationString=="+locationString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        String currentLocation = "The location is changed to Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng;
        Toast.makeText(this,currentLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        p = new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);


        // check in database if we have same lattitude & longitude

        MySQLiteHelper m=new MySQLiteHelper(getBaseContext());
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<LocWiseProfileBeans> LocWiseProfile= m.getAllLocWiseProfile();       


        for (LocWiseProfileBeans cn : LocWiseProfile) {
            String log = "Loc Name: "+cn.getLocname()+" ,Lattitude: " + cn.getLattitude()+ " ,Longitude: " + cn.getLongitude()+ " , Selected Profile :"+cn.getSelectedprofile();
                // Writing Contacts to log
            double distance2=00.00;

      GeoPoint storedLocation=new GeoPoint(
      (int) cn.getLattitude() * 1000000,(int) cn.getLongitude() * 1000000);    

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");  

        locationB.setLatitude((int) cn.getLattitude() * 1000000);  
        locationB.setLongitude((int) cn.getLongitude() * 1000000);  


        distance2=distFrom(lat,lng,cn.getLattitude(),cn.getLongitude());


        if(distance2>1 )
        {
            Log.d("Name: ", log);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loc Name:"+log, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this,"identical", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this,"distance2======"+distance2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
sendnotification("Locale Notifications","You visited location " + cn.getLocname());


        }
```

This code are use to notify the user.

```
protected void sendnotification (String title, String message) {
       String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
       NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

       int icon = R.drawable.icon;
       CharSequence tickerText = message;
       long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

       Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       CharSequence contentTitle = title;
       CharSequence contentText = message;
       Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, GoogleMapsActivity.class);
       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

       notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
       mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Here is function for converting longitude and latitude into miles.

```
public static double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) { 
      double earthRadius = 3958.75; 
      double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1); 
      double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1); 
      double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * 
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2); 
      double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
      double dist = earthRadius * c; 

      return dist; 
    }
```

you need to change where required as per your code....

Comment: i unable to understand your code it would be helpful if u figure out the error in my code...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

You can register a `LocationListener` to `LocationManager` with some time or distance interval settings, then when location is changed, can compare it to what you have set to decide whether to notify the user.

GPS consumes large battery power, so you should better first use Network Location Provider, then when it's not so far to that location, start the GPS.

---

As the comment said, you should first move

```
tasklocation.setLatitude(22.727733);
tasklocation.setLongitude(75.886079);
```

above

`double dis1 = location.distanceTo(tasklocation);`

(Better, you could move these location setting out of `onLocationChanged()` and not hardcode Latitude/Longitude.)

This may not solve your problem ,but not doing this will NEVER make it work. So do not leave some mistake like that.

---

Then, I should say this code works for me (in my emulator) and I can not see other mistakes for what you give that may give you "not working".

You may check your permissions for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Or may show the `Toast` result or `Logcat` output.

After all, more details about your "not working".

Comment: I have already added the permission and made the changes u said but the code is still not working . While testing the code on phone when i go to the location no notification comes. This code works fine on the emulator.

Comment: Add some code to `onLocationChanged()` to show `dis1` for every location change (for example, output to `TextView`). Show the result.